# Generate log transformation of all columns in R

Tags: r

I have 100 non-negative columns in my dataframe and would like to create the log transformation of each of them in R. How do I accomplish this? I'd ideally like to retain the original variables name and append the suffix "_log" to the new variables.

Comment: May be something like `yourdf[paste0(names(yourdf), '_log')] <- lapply(yourdf, function(x) log(x))`

Comment: I think that just `log(your_data)` should work well for matrices because indeed they are just vectors with dimensional attributes. If your data is a data frame things change as said by akrun.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do

```
newdata <- log(data)
```

You can then do something like (untested)

```
names(newdata) <- paste0(names(data), "_log")
```